# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation

Tags: java, groovy

I have a problem when I try to run my project
The exception is :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation
```

I have added these libs to my project and to my classpath

```
commons-beanutils-1.8.0
commons-collections-2.1.1
commons-digester-1.7
commons-javaflow-20060411
commons-logging-1.0.4
groovy-all-1.8.6
iText-2.1.7
jasperreports-5.2.0
jcommon-1.0.17
jfreechart-1.0.13
```

I follow some solution to this website but I still have the Exception...
I have this problem since 2 days and I never get solutions and now I really need help.
Thanks!!!

Comment: Is this a web application/standalone? how do you run this project? you need to provide more information

Comment: Without example of the way You run the application it's very difficult to help You. Maybe You just need a dependency tool?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a dependency manager (Maven, SBT, Ivy, Gradle, etc.) copy and paste the respective snippet above into your project file. If you're using a dependency manager, that's all there is to resolving this exception.

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/info/novatec/testit/livingdoc-confluence5-plugin/1.1.2/livingdoc-confluence5-plugin-1.1.2.jar

Comment: same problem i face and solve after adding this lib.

Answer (score 0):

All of the [following jars/dependencies](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3A%22org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation%22), contain a class with the same name as your missing class. Add the correct jar/dependency (preferably the one relevant to your project), to the classpath of your project, and you should no longer receive the error.

You can download the JAR directly, or configure a build tool to do your dependency management for you. (e.g. ivy+ant, gradle, maven, [etc](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-build-tools-how-dependency-management-works-with-maven-gradle-and-ant-ivy/))

Additionally, [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) provides instructions on manually adding a JAR to your classpath.

Ask if you need more help with this.